# Problems with Django Hitcount Module

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the [django-hitcount](http://blog.damontimm.com/django-hitcount-app-count-hits-views/) module to save the number of times a tutorial is accessed by different users.

The module is correctly installed as explained [in the blog](http://blog.damontimm.com/django-hitcount-app-count-hits-views/). The hitcount template tag seems to return the correct result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        {% get_hit_count_javascript for tut_contents %}
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // returns
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post( '/tutorial/ajax/hit/',
        { hitcount_pk : '1' },
        function(data, status) {
                if (data.status == 'error') {
            // do something for error?
                }
            },
        'json');
    });
</script>
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from hitcount.views import update_hit_count_ajax
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = patterns('tutorial.views',
    (r'^$', 'root'),
    # Hitcount url to save hits on tutorial entity
    url(r'^ajax/hit/$', update_hit_count_ajax, name='hitcount_update_ajax'),
)
```

The problem is when I check my debugger.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (FORBIDDEN)
POST http://waaave.com.dev:8000/tutorial/ajax/hit/ 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

(That's probably why nothing is saved in hitcount_hit table)

Comment: Also, in addition to my answer, I just found that the subject of adding csrf in the request is also mentioned in the comments of the tutorial you are using.

Comment: Thank you yuvi. For people interested, check this fork: https://github.com/zaebee/django-hitcount It will insert the csrf token. But I have another problem, now it tells me POST http://waaave.com.dev:8000/tutorial/ajax/hit/ 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: Looking at your urls I suspect you are linking the view to: `http://waaave.com.dev:8000/ajax/hit/`. change it to `url(r'^tutorial/ajax/hit/$'` and it will probably work

Comment: Thank you very much. It works and Django Unchained is the best movie! :)

Comment: Sure thing, happy to have helped =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are sending the request as POST and getting a 403 Forbidden, I'm going to guess this is a problem with csrf token, which in django is required in every POST request.

Solving it is easy. Just copy the getCookie function [from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) and either send it with the header like they explain, or simply add it to your data in the request like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post( '/tutorial/ajax/hit/',
    { 'hitcount_pk' : '1',
     'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken') },
    function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == 'error') {
        // do something for error?
            }
        },
    'json');
 });
```